# How do I disable the windows 7 activation system in this situation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

My windows somehow "expired" and I need to activate it or its not Genuine, and it'll shut down every hour. That's normal. I've seen couple ways to activate it like putting in activation keys, but I am tired of doing so.I found out that usually when you go to control panel>admin. tools>computer management>system protection and disable it as well as the updates, it'll stop.But my computer can't disable it. It just says in grey, "Automatic (Delayed Start).Is it because the windows7 is expired? I am a administrator user, so I do have access to all admin stuff.

[image: a screenshot of the problem . . .]

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - you need to concentrate on *why* the activation isn't sticking, rather than ways to prevent the activation process from happening.

Comment: You call the Microsoft Activation Center, have you done that, it takes less than 5 minutes to activate Windows by phone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1: Regedit:**

Please navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc` and locate Start registry key

[image: regedit]

Double click on Start and edit the value:

Change Startup type :

- Automatic - 2
- Manual - 3
- Disabled - 4
- Automatic (Delayed Start) - 2

[image]

**Note:** When you change to Automatic (Delayed Start) a new key `DelayedAutostart` is created with value `1`.
When you change to Automatic from Automatic (Delayed Start), `DelayedAutostart` change value to `0`.

---

**Method 2: Command Prompt:**

Type `cmd`, right click on cmd icon under the Programs and click on Run as administrator

Please select, right and copy a registry key from below, then right click on command prompt window, select Paste and press Enter

To Stop Software Protection:

net stop sppsvc

To change Startup Type:

Automatic:

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

Manual:

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

Disabled:

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
```

Automatic (Delayed Start):

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

**Note:** When you change to Automatic (Delayed Start) a new key `DelayedAutostart` is created with value `1`.

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

When you change to Automatic from Automatic (Delayed Start), `DelayedAutostart` change value to `0`.

```
REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sppsvc" /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Reference:

[How to Start/Stop Software Protection service](http://computerstepbystep.com/software_protection_service.html)